# What kinds of i/o error returns when remove disk abnormally?

Tags: c++, c, linux, aio, disk-io

What kinds of i/o error returns when remove disk abnormally(physically)?

I use linux aio functions to i/o files.

If I remove disk abnormally after "io_submit(control blocks with i/o infos)",

suspend aio(io_getevents) will return events with EBADF or EDISK? or something else?

It's hard to test on cloud, so I ask for u guys.

Comment: You seem to be specifically mentioning some api. Could you prepare a sample compilable program to test it? I suspect `EIO` will be the errno, but I suspect that really depends at what exactly time is the disc removed (and the data may also be cached, so it may return success). I see [`aio_suspend`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/aio_suspend.html) can't return EBADF nor EDISK, it most probably will succeed; use `aio_return`

Comment: What is `suspend_aio`?  Do you mean `aio_suspend`?  The man page tells you it can return EAGAIN, EINTR, or ENOSYS.  Use `aio_error` to get the error that occurred.

Comment: You'll only get `EIO`.  You'll need to use some other mechanism to detect if the disk has been removed.

Comment: Actually there **are** ways to test this by creating fake devices that can suddenly return errors even in the cloud assuming you're in a VM where you have root access. See the [list of Linux disk fault injection mechanisms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144200/109111).